# Getting ggplot scale_fill_manual correct (aes color)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hopefully have a simple question, but after looking up similar questions I'm still not sure what I am doing wrong.

Reproducible example (fake data):

```
# data
pay <- c(rep(c(100,125,200,225), 6))
title <- c(rep(c("Jr", "Mid", "Sr", "Exec"), 6))
dept <- c(rep(c("Finance", "Acctg", "Sales", "Sales"), 6))

mydf <- data.frame(pay, title, dept)
mycolors <- c("#000000", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442")

# plot
myplot <- ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = dept, y = pay, fill = title)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = title), width = 0.33) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Total Comp $", labels = comma, breaks = seq(0, 250, 50) ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=mycolors) +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust = 1, size=10))
myplot
```

**My problem:**  I was expecting to have my colors ("mycolors" variable) used in plotting the points, but the default ggplot colors are being used instead.  I would have thought the scale_fill_manual would have overridden the default colors, but they appear not to be.

An explanation with the solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The default points in ggplot2 can't be filled.  You used `color` to color the points, so need `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it, thank you for the explanation and solution!

Comment: Also: you can use `fill` for certain point shapes! If you use `geom_jitter(aes(fill = title), width = 0.33, shape = 21)` with `scale_fill_manual` you'll see.

Comment: Helpful, thank you Brian!